# Posting Complete Solutions?

Tags: discussion, questions

After posting 7 questions on Stack Overflow, and various searching on YouTube and other sites, as well as input from several colleagues, I've been able to solve my issues with PHP, Dreamweaver CS3, Xampp, and the ability to test the use of PHP includes on my localhost server. It took approximately 1 week to gather all the information necessary to actually get it up and running smoothly.

I'm wondering if there is a place here on Stack Overflow where someone such as myself might provide/post a somewhat comprehensive solution to this problem for someone in the future so that they don't have to ask 7 questions on the site and seek a weeks worth of assistance from various other sources, as I have needed to?

I respect the process here, as it's been helpful to me. Just wondering how we might go about contributing larger suggestions on how to solve bigger problems such as integrating a number of elements together, as was the case here?

Would it be acceptable to just post my final solution, rather than asking a question?

Answer (score 7):

Ask the question, then answer it yourself.  Have your answer ready, and paste it in quick to avoid people wasting time.  Better yet, include the fact that you'll be self answering in the question.

Comment: TheSoftwareJedi. Your site (linked to from your profile) is broken.

Comment: The problem with asking and answering questions is that some self appointed heroes who didn't read the FAQ are going around closing every such question down!

Comment: But you can't accept you own answer as a question (because of gamesmanship).

Comment: You can if you make the answer community wiki.  I think.

Comment: You can accept your answer, though you might need to wait 48 hours. You merely gain nothing in terms of rep.

Comment: @outis: You couldn't when this answer was written. :)

Comment: @mmyers: Ah, the inevitable march of progress.

Comment: Frankly, this is a less-than-perfect solution. A separated, well-organized section devoted to ready-to-use, commonly-requested/ commonly-used solutions would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a blog it might be a very good place to go for a detailed problem and solution description. You can link to the questions here on SO and to other sources from the blog post.

If you don't have a blog, this is the perfect excuse to start one :)

Comment: Agree, having a personal blog is great to share information you have gathered. Especially when it is hard to get the needed information. You may end up helping someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this, is to ask the question and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the charges of 'Reputation Harvesting' when posting answers to your own question, mark the question as 'Community Wiki'. Maybe the site should do this automatically if the question writer is the first to post an answer?

Skizz

Comment: That's a brilliant idea, it should be a uservoice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me in my first question, when none of the answers were really what I was looking for. Eventually I continued to google and read some relevant reference material until I found the answer for myself.

I posted the answer to my question, but the thing is, I can't "accept" my own answer!!! so  when I had enough points, I just closed the question and edited it to put the answer as a part of the question.

Comment: I think you could have accepted the answer if you posted it as a community wiki answer.